# MySQL query: show number of entries by day

Tags: mysql

I have a table with structure:

```
id|name|       date
---------------------------
 1|qwer|2011-08-29 13:11:59
 2|wert|2011-08-29 13:11:59
 3|erty|2011-08-30 13:11:59
 4|rtyu|2011-08-31 13:11:59
```

I need a query to show data like this:

```
    day   |number_of_entries
----------------------------
2011-08-29|                2
2011-08-30|                1
2011-08-31|                1
```

Comment: Heh, this was simple:

    select date_format(date, "%Y-%m-%d") as 'day', count(id) as 'count' from table
    group by date_format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `GROUP BY` function and the `COUNT` function gives the following:

```
SELECT DATE(`date`), COUNT(*) AS number_of_entires
FROM tablename
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
ORDER BY `date`
```

[GROUP BY - MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

[DATE - MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: Bear in mind that this doesn't cater for days where there've been no entries - so, you will never have `2011-08-29 | 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   DATE(`date`) AS day,
         COUNT(*)     AS number_of_entries
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Use MySQL's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.